# monosubstitution cypher : decryption in python 2.7 list trouble

Tags: python-2.7

I'm currently coding a simple monosubsubstitution cypher in python. The encryption goes this way: first a key to encypher is produce this way

```
def non_random_key(key_name):
    my_alphabet = []
    for char in alphabet:
        my_alphabet.append(char)

    my_key_alphabet = list(key_name)

    for char in key_name:
        my_alphabet.remove(char)
    return my_key_alphabet + my_alphabet
```

Then a message is encrypted with this key this way

```
def crypt_message(message, key):
    message = remove_whitespace_ponc(message)
    message = message.upper()
    encrypted_message = []
    for char in message:
        if char == 'A':
            encrypted_message.append(key[0])
        elif char == 'B':
            encrypted_message.append(key[1])
        elif char == 'C':
            encrypted_message.append(key[2])
        elif char == 'D':
            encrypted_message.append(key[3])
        elif char == 'E':
            encrypted_message.append(key[4])
        elif char == 'F':
            encrypted_message.append(key[5])
        elif char == 'G':
            encrypted_message.append(key[6])
        elif char == 'H':
            encrypted_message.append(key[7])
        elif char == 'I':
            encrypted_message.append(key[8])
        elif char == 'J':
            encrypted_message.append(key[9])
        elif char == 'K':
            encrypted_message.append(key[10])
        elif char == 'L':
            encrypted_message.append(key[11])
        elif char == 'M':
            encrypted_message.append(key[12])
        elif char == 'N':
            encrypted_message.append(key[13])
        elif char == 'O':
            encrypted_message.append(key[14])
        elif char == 'P':
            encrypted_message.append(key[15])
        elif char == 'Q':
            encrypted_message.append(key[16])
        elif char == 'R':
            encrypted_message.append(key[17])
        elif char == 'S':
            encrypted_message.append(key[18])
        elif char == 'T':
            encrypted_message.append(key[19])
        elif char == 'U':
            encrypted_message.append(key[20])
        elif char == 'U':
            encrypted_message.append(key[21])
        elif char == 'V':
            encrypted_message.append(key[22])
        elif char == 'W':
            encrypted_message.append(key[23])
        elif char == 'X':
            encrypted_message.append(key[24])
        elif char == 'Y':
            encrypted_message.append(key[25])
    return ''.join(encrypted_message)
```

Finally I tried to decode my encrypted message with this function:

```
def decrypt(encrypted_message, key):
    decrypted_message = encrypted_message
    print decrypted_message
    decrypted_message = decrypted_message.replace(key[0], alphabet[0])
    print decrypted_message
    decrypted_message = decrypted_message.replace(key[1], alphabet[1])
    print decrypted_message
    decrypted_message = decrypted_message.replace(key[2], alphabet[2])
    print decrypted_message
    decrypted_message = decrypted_message.replace(key[3], alphabet[3])
    print decrypted_message
    decrypted_message = decrypted_message.replace(key[4], alphabet[4])
    print decrypted_message
    decrypted_message = decrypted_message.replace(key[5], alphabet[5])
    print decrypted_message
    decrypted_message = decrypted_message.replace(key[6], alphabet[6])
    print decrypted_message
    decrypted_message = decrypted_message.replace(key[7], alphabet[7])
    print decrypted_message
    decrypted_message = decrypted_message.replace(key[8], alphabet[8])
    print decrypted_message
    decrypted_message = decrypted_message.replace(key[9], alphabet[9])
    print decrypted_message
    decrypted_message = decrypted_message.replace(key[10], alphabet[10])
    print decrypted_message
    decrypted_message = decrypted_message.replace(key[11], alphabet[11])
    print decrypted_message
    decrypted_message = decrypted_message.replace(key[12], alphabet[12])
    print decrypted_message
    decrypted_message = decrypted_message.replace(key[13], alphabet[13])
    print decrypted_message
    decrypted_message = decrypted_message.replace(key[14], alphabet[14])
    print decrypted_message
    decrypted_message = decrypted_message.replace(key[15], alphabet[15])
    print decrypted_message
    decrypted_message = decrypted_message.replace(key[16], alphabet[16])
    print decrypted_message
    decrypted_message = decrypted_message.replace(key[17], alphabet[17])
    print decrypted_message
    decrypted_message = decrypted_message.replace(key[18], alphabet[18])
    print decrypted_message
    decrypted_message = decrypted_message.replace(key[19], alphabet[19])
    print decrypted_message
    decrypted_message = decrypted_message.replace(key[20], alphabet[20])
    print decrypted_message
    decrypted_message = decrypted_message.replace(key[21], alphabet[21])
    print decrypted_message
    decrypted_message = decrypted_message.replace(key[22], alphabet[22])
    print decrypted_message
    decrypted_message = decrypted_message.replace(key[23], alphabet[23])
    print decrypted_message
    decrypted_message = decrypted_message.replace(key[24], alphabet[24])
    print decrypted_message
    decrypted_message = decrypted_message.replace(key[25], alphabet[25])
    print decrypted_message

    return decrypted_message
```

I added the print decrypted_message statement as a try to understand what is happening because the output is quite odd. In fact:

```
print non_random_key('ROUGE')
msg = crypt_message('AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA', non_random_key('ROUGE'))
print decrypt(msg, non_random_key('ROUGE'))

['R', 'O', 'U', 'G', 'E', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'F', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K','L', 'M', 'N', 'P', 'Q', 'S', 'T', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
JJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJ
JJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJ
JJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJ
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP
PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP
RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR
RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR
RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR
RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR
RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR
RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR
RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR
RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR
RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR
RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR
```

I clearly don't understand why there is this behavior.
Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems that I have noticed:

1. In encrypt function:

   ```
   elif char == 'U':
       encrypted_message.append(key[20])
   elif char == 'U':
       encrypted_message.append(key[21])
   ```

   Change it to:

   ```
   elif char == 'U':
       encrypted_message.append(key[20])
   elif char == 'V':
       encrypted_message.append(key[21])
   ```
2. In decrypt function:
   Doing `decrypted_message = decrypted_message.replace(key[i], alphabet[i])` `for i in range(0,25)`, this might replace the decrypted character with some another character.

   For example:

   In the case of `msg='AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'`, encrypted message is `RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR`. On decrypting it using the provided key, in will get decrypted by `decrypted_message.replace(key[0], alphabet[0])`. Now doing `decrypted_message.replace(key[5], alphabet[5])` will change the previous value of decrypted_message. And this will continue till the last.

You can decrypte using:

```
def decrypt(encrypted_message, key):
    decrypted_message = ''
    for i in range(0,len(encrypted_message)):
        decrypted_message += alphabet[key.index(encrypted_message[i])]
    return decrypted_message
```